# NodeJS returning JSON, but not to client properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

So, I have a route that is authing a user based on username and password input. The first validation check, I just can't seem to get to work:

```
exports.user_login = (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
        if (err || !user) {
            res.status(500).json({
                errorMsg: "User could not be authenticated."
            });
        }
```

If I ping this via postman, I get the appropriate JSON response back that the `User could not be authenticated`.

However, if I use this route from my client-side code, and try to `console.log` it, or whatever else (essentially, I want to pull whatever the `errorMsg` is, log it in state, and reflect that back to the user), then I just get the following response:

```
axios.post("api/auth/login/", user)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                this.setState({
                    username: "",
                    password: ""
                })
                localStorage.setItem('bdgt', res.data.token);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);

            })
```

[image]

I've looked at other code I've done before, and usually this works, and I can typically access the message and store it to state by:

```
this.setState({
     error: err.errorMsg
})
```

Thoughts? What am I missing?

EDIT ... If I just let it do `res.json({ errorMsg: "message....."})` ... this works just fine, but returns a `200` which is obviously not what I want.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab, and the actual request? Could be more details there

Comment: Show your client side code please

Comment: Yeah, so going into the network tab, and clicking on the request that had the error actually shows the JSON message I want.... but I can't figure out how to access this.

I don't know if I'm just doing something differently than normal, or if something has actually changed in a recent update.

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon the client code is the `.catch`. I am updating the original post to include the whole, in case that helps somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when `axios` get a response which status is greater or equal to 400 it throws an exception. You can access your response data like this

```js
axios.post("api/auth/login/", user)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                this.setState({
                    username: "",
                    password: ""
                })
                localStorage.setItem('bdgt', res.data.token);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err.response.data); // this is your JSON

            })
```

Comment: That's the one! Thanks Gor.